# How can I assign a column to represent the x axis values in libre office calc?

Tags: libreoffice, database, csv

Currently my attempt at making a chart looks like this:

[image]

The goal, nonetheless Is that subdivisions, should be the x axis and not a series of data entries in the chart. I have looked it up but I am still confused as to hwo to achieve this.

Comment: What Chart Type did you choose? it needs to be **XY (Scatter)**

Comment: I had chosen line

Comment: So... do you get the desired result if you use a scatter plot?

Comment: Yes, I also figured that editing the data entries after creating the plot worked as well